# User interaction through view issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please help me to turn off user interaction.
I have a custom view which appears for several seconds on the top level of view hierarchy. There are several buttons under the view. The problem is that buttons catch touch events when user clicks on view. I've set myCustomView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; And nothing happens. Buttons catch events through view all the same. How to create a view which will not allow to intercept touches through it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `myCustomView` is at the top level of view hierarchy, I imagine you are trying to implement something like an overlay view, that covers the other views translucently. In this case, setting `userInteractionEnabled = NO` on this view will cause touch events to be forwarded to the views below.

The correct way is to set `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on your custom view, then either create a transparent button to reroute touch to a dismiss IBAction, or ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable user interaction on a common superview of the buttons:

```
someButton.superview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Another way to disable UI while some overlay UI is on top is to put the overlay in its own window instead on top of the existing views.

Answer (score 0):

use:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]`

for ignoring the user events. And after few seconds and your view dissapears, you can use:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents]`

This way you can solve your problem.